# Deformation retraction in proof of Brown's theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory

I am trying to understand the proof of Lemma 4E.4 at page 451 of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology [https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf)

but I am at a loss regarding the passage "so $K'$ deformation retracts onto $K$". I can see why the inclusion is a weak homotopy equivalence, but then what?

Also, I think we are supposed to prove a $\textit{strong}$ deformation retraction since in the following line it is said to induce a homotopy relative to A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, but Hatcher uses "deformation retraction" for what should be "strong (strict) deformation retraction" - see the definition of p. 2.

As to why $K′$ deformation retracts onto  $K$: Corollary 0.20 says that if an inclusion $A \hookrightarrow X$ is a homotopy equivalence then it has a deformation retraction. Weak homotopy equivalence implies that $K \hookrightarrow K'$ satisfies the Corollary assumption.